# Add a new instance of movie clip each time I click

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

I'm trying to create a movie clip every time I click the stage. I know that addChild does not add new instances, so every time I click, the previous cube disappears. I tried using an array to create multiple movie clips with no success. I'm pretty new to ActionScript, so I'm sorry for this naive question.

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, spawnCube);

var i:int = 0;
var p1:cube = new cube();

function spawnCube(event:MouseEvent):void
{
p1.name = "p1";
p1.x = mouseX;
p1.y = mouseY;

arr.push(p1);
addChild(arr[i]);
i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `new Cube()` call into your click handler, this way it'll create a new cube properly.

```
function spawnCube(event:MouseEvent):void
{
     var p1:Cube=new Cube(); // this
     p1.x = mouseX;
     p1.y = mouseY;
     arr.push(p1);
     addChild(p1); // also this, because now "p1" has a new cube each time
     i++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only one instance of Cube so every time you call `addChild()` you just place the same instance in other place. You have to create new cube `var p1:cube = new cube();` every time you click.